# VS Code go to source for Python3 built-ins

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code

How can I see the source code of Python builtin functions in Visual Studio Code? For example, how do I see the source code for `print()` when I control click on it?

Comment: Many Python builtins are implemented in C and their source code is not locally available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS Code presents you with skeleton methods that show just the function signatures. Python's built-in functions for [CPython](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPython) are written in C and compiled into bytecode to be interpreted during execution time.

If you'd like to view the source code for some built-in methods, you'll have to check the source code of your Python interpreter.

See `print` implementation for CPython, Python default interpreter:
https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Python/bltinmodule.c#L1947

Built-in functions source: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/bltinmodule.c

Built-in types: https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/master/Objects